# Open Source query builder tool for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, open-source, query-builder

Okie, I've searched it in SO and I've not found it. Can someone tell me a good open source query builder tool for working with Microsoft SQL Server databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBVisualizer will do the trick. It's Opensource and can be configured to use with almost any DBMS.

[DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/)

[DBVisualizer Query Builder](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/doc/main/doc/ug/queryBuilder/queryBuilder.html)

Comment: I can't find the source code for DBVisualizer.  Are you sure it's open source?

Comment: Any such tool with source code ?

Comment: check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqleo/

Answer (score 1):

What about [Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)?  But, it is not open source.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx).

Comment: Can I actually 'build' queries there visually? I thought we need to type the queries manually by checking the column names, table names etc.

Comment: Look like what you want http://www.ehow.com/video_4982928_using-query-builder-sql-server.html